RHEL 9: black screen after login (ASMB11-iKVM)
Fresh install of RHEL9, once logged in, I get a black screen for Gnome Classic using X11 and Wayland.
Using ASMB11-iKVM BMC. No issue with anything else.
What can I do to debug that?
